# How to Prevent save to Database in Hibernate on transaction commit?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Giving some context - I am migrating my database to some other platform on which Hibernate queries are not supported. Since there are a lot of places where Hibernate concepts are used, I plan to change `load()`, `save()`, and `delete()` functions at the DAO layer to work on the new database rather than changing at the service layer. But, one problem is when Hibernate saves itself when a transaction is committed. How can I avoid that?

When a transaction is committed in Hibernate the persistent entities in the session are saved to the database. Since I am using the `@Transactional` annotation of Spring I don't have control over this. My requirement is that I want to prevent objects from being saving into the database by Hibernate and save objects myself using the DAO inside the class using the `@Transactional` annotation. Also, I read about stateless sessions of Hibernate, so would it be a good idea to use them as I am not saving anything to the session? I read about this but couldn't find a concrete solution to this. Can some Hibernate + Spring expert help in this regard?

Comment: what other platform? what persistence API are you using?

Comment: Matrix Database which is nosql and I am using JDBC as of now

Comment: I am migrating to Matrix database which is NoSql and as of now I am using JDBC

Comment: you're using JDBC for your new database? and what API for your current database? if there is a JDBC driver then you can easily enough write an adapter/dialect/whateverItsCalled for your JPA provider

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch to manual flush:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the database not supported by Hibernate maybe the best solution is to throws hibernate and just using spring + jdbc template, so you have full control on it.

Comment: There are a lot of places where this is used and moreover this provides the functionality of transactions and sessions by itself so just trying to figure out some means t do it.